# dropdown bind issue in kendo issue

Tags: templates, kendo-ui, grid

I have requirement to display dropdownlist in one column with data ,in other column i need to display list of checkboxes. How can i show it weather can use client template or template. (i need to display in page load and user should select the options without edit.)

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model.listItems)
    .Name("Grid")
    .TableHtmlAttributes(new { @class = "table-responsive table table-bordered table-scrollable table-hover table-striped dataTable", style = "" })
    .BindTo(Model.listItems)
    .DataSource(data => data
        .Ajax()
            .Model(
                    m =>
                    {
                        m.Field(esc => esc.List1);
                        m.Field(esc => esc.List2);
                    }
                )   
            .Create(create => create.Action("DecisionsAndRoeles", "Admin"))  //Dummy action

        )
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(p => p.List1).Title("Role").Template(@<text></text>).HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "templateCell" }).ClientTemplate(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
                    .Name("RoleSets")
                    .OptionLabel("Please Select")
                    .BindTo("#=List1#")
                    .DataTextField("Description")
                    .DataValueField("RoleId").ToClientTemplate()
                    .ToHtmlString()
                    ).Width(200);//"#=generateTemplate(ListRoles)#");//.ClientTemplate(ruleSetDropDown.ToString()); 
        columns.Bound(p => p.List2).Title("Decision Options").ClientTemplate
            ("<div class='col-lg-11'>" +
               "<div class='row' style='margin-top:2px>" +
                 "<div class='row'>" +
                     "<div class='row'>" +

                     "</div>" +
                     "<div class='col-md-12' >" +
                       "#for(var i=0; i<List2.Count;i++)" +
                        "{#" +
                             "<div class='col-md-6'>" +
                                 "<div class='col-md-6'>" +
                                         "<input type='checkbox' class='chkDecisionOption' id='chkDecisionOpt'  onchange='checkboxClick(this)' value='test' name='test' /> List2[i].Description" +
                                         "</div>" +
                                "<div class='col-md-6'>" +

                               "</div>" +

                                "</div>" +

                        "#}#" +
                   " </div>" +
                   "  </div>  " +
                 "</div>" +
            "</div>");                          
    }
    )
    .Pageable()
    .Sortable()
    .Scrollable()
            .ToolBar(commands => commands.Create()).Events(e => { e.DataBound("gridDecisionDataBound");  })  
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .PageSize(20)
        .Model(model => model.Id(p => p.id))


    )
)
```

Issue: Dropdown data and also other column data not populating .

Comment: any one have idea on this...?

Comment: or else any other way to accomplish this .